# Ho do I add pagination to a query that has checkboxes?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pagination, checkbox

So I have an example of a query that was graciously provided by Frost which has helped me learn SO much ( I am very much a newbie) but I am stuck trying to add pagination. I have been scouring the web for a week now and there are so many different examples and I have tried so many of them with little or no success. I was finally able to build what you see below, the problem is that when you hit search it does indeed only return 20 records but the pages don't work. The way they dont work is that when you click 'next' it will go to page two but no results show up, and if you click again expecting page 3 it wont go there it stays on page 2. I really did not want to take anyone's valuable time but I am just so very lost. Here is "my" code:

```
    <?php

    //we select all the License records
    $req_limit = mysql_query("Select License from OPLR");
    $result = mysql_numrows($req_limit);//mysql_numrows() give us the result of the     request

    // now we will use the result to limit the displayed messages
    $page_limit = '20'; //we chose the number of messages by page
    // here we divide the total by the number of messages we choose
    $page_number = $result / $page_limit; 

    // we round the number of pages to avoid commas.
    $total_number = ceil($page_number); 

    // here we take of one page because the first page will be displyed is number one
    $number = $total_number - 1; 

    // if the variable number_page is equal or defferent to 0
    if(isset($_GET['page_number']) || $_GET['page_number'] != '0' ) 

    {
    // multiplies the page limit with the current number page on the url
    $mysql_limit = $page_limit * $_GET['page_number']; 

    }
    else{ // no variable number_page

    $mysql_limit = '0'; // the limit is 0

    }

    ?>

    <?php
    /*****************************
     *  Simple SQL Search Tutorial by Frost
     *  of Slunked.com
     ******************************/



    // Set up our error check and result check array
    $error = array();
    $results = array();

    // First check if a form was submitted. 
    // Since this is a search we will use $_GET
    if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
       $searchTerms = trim($_GET['search']);
       $searchTerms = strip_tags($searchTerms); // remove any html/javascript.

       if (strlen($searchTerms) < 0) {
  $error[] = "Search terms must be longer than 3 characters.";
       }else {
          $searchTermDB = mysql_real_escape_string($searchTerms); // prevent sql         injection.
       }

       // If there are no errors, lets get the search going.
               if (count($error) < 1) {

          $searchSQL = "SELECT License, Pet_Name, Owner_Name, Species, Notes, Unowned FROM OPLR WHERE ";

  // grab the search types.
  $types = array();
  $types[] = isset($_GET['License'])?"`License` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
  $types[] = isset($_GET['Pet_Name'])?"`Pet_Name` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
  $types[] = isset($_GET['Owner_Name'])?"`Owner_Name` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
  $types[] = isset($_GET['Species'])?"`Species` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
  $types[] = isset($_GET['Unowned'])?"`Unowned` LIKE 'y'":'';

   $types = array_filter($types, "removeEmpty"); // removes any item that was empty (not checked)

  if (count($types) < 1)
     $types[] = "`Pet_Name` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'"; // use the Pet_Name as a default search if none are checked

      $andOr = isset($_GET['matchall'])?'AND':'OR';


  $searchSQL .= implode(" {$andOr} ", $types) . " ORDER BY `Pet_Name`"; // order by Pet Name.

  $searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>"         . mysql_error() . "<br 

    />SQL Was: {$searchSQL}");

  if (mysql_num_rows($searchResult) < 1) {
     $error[] = "The search term provided {$searchTerms} yielded no results.";
  }else {
     $results = array(); // the result array
     $i = 1;
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)) {
        $results[] = "<B>License Number: {$row['License']}</B><br />Pet Name: {$row['Pet_Name']}<br /> Owner Name: {$row['Owner_Name']}<br />Species: {$row['Species']}<br />Notes: {$row['Notes']}<br /><br />";
        $i++;
     }
  }
       }
    }


    ?>
    <?php echo (count($error) > 0)?"The following had errors:<br /><span         id=\"error\">" . implode("<br />", 

    $error) . "</span><br /><br />":""; ?>
       <form method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"         name="searchForm" id="searchform">

           <fieldset>
     <center><p>Search For:
     <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo         isset($searchTerms)?htmlspecialchars

    ($searchTerms):''; ?>" /></p></center>
   </fieldset>




         <fieldset>


     <div id="checks"><center>
       License Number: 
       <input type="checkbox" name="License" value="on" <?php echo         isset($_GET['License'])?"checked":''; ?> />      
       |    


     Species: 
       <input type="checkbox" name="Species" value="on" <?php echo         isset($_GET['Species'])?"checked":''; ?> /> 
        |  &nbsp;     
     Unowned: 
     <input type="checkbox" name="Unowned" value="on" <?php echo         isset($_GET['Unowned'])?"checked":''; ?> />
     <br />
             Match All Selected Fields? <input type="checkbox" name="matchall"         value="on" <?php echo isset($_GET['matchall'])?"checked":''; ?> />
 <br /><br />

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search!" /></center></div>
 </fieldset>
       </form>
       <?php echo (count($error) >         0)?"The following had errors:<br /><span         id=\"error\">" .   implode("<br />", 

    $error) . "</span><br /><br />":""; ?>

      <?php echo (count($results) > 0)?"Your search: {$searchTerms} <br> <b>Returned:        </b><br /><br />" . implode("", 

    $results):""; 
    ?>
    <?php
    // If the page number different of 0 and if the page_number is unset
    if( $number != '0' && empty($_GET['page_number']))
    {
    print '<a href="registry.php?page_number=1">Next page</a>'; // we set the         page_number to 1
    }

    // in this condition, the variable page_number is set and its value is less than         $number
    elseif($number !='0' && isset($_GET['page_number']) && $_GET['page_number']         <             $number)
    {
           $next = $_GET['page_number'] + 1; // add 1 to the current page number
    print '<a href="registry.php?page_number='.$suivant.'">next page</a>'; //The link         for the next pages
    // go back to the precedent page, we used a java-script code to do it print         '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript: history.back();">Previous page</a>';
    }

    // here, the link that will be displayed when the page number is reched
    elseif( $number !='0' && isset($_GET['page_number']) && $_GET['page_number'] >= $number )
    {
    print '<a href="javascript: history.back();">Previous page</a>';
    }
    function removeEmpty($var) {
       return (!empty($var)); 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: The corresponding html might be helpful

Comment: Thanks for responding! There really is no corresponding html that relates to the query, its all just formating divs for my css script. Am i missing html that needs to be implemented outside the script so it functions?

Comment: Not entirely related, but it might prove useful in the future _not_ to use the `mysql_*` extention anymore. It's being deprecated (finally). Please look into `PDO` or `mysqli_*`, they support features like _prepared statements_ and tons of other goodies that didn't exist back in the `mysql_*` days (was written for MySQL 3.x, current version is 5.5)

Comment: there is no relationship between checkboxes and mysql queries. at least your html form should be relevant. I suspect a POST/GET mixup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems. First one is that you use a form submit to get the values from the options (which is fine) but the link "next page" just gives a page_id and not all the other options. (You could either put them in the next link (as you use _GET anyways) or store the submitted values in a sessionn. I'd prefer the latter).

The other problem is, that you do some pagination calculation, but u never use the number you calculated. You have to put in an mysql LIMIT statement. ( There right point for that would be after the "ORDER BY". For that replace

```
" ORDER BY `Pet_Name`";
```

by

```
" ORDER BY `Pet_Name` LIMIT ". $mysql_limit .",". $page_limit;
```

But remember, this will only fix problem 2, you still have to put those _GET Variables into the "next page"

Comment: I put the limit statement in as you have it and thank you so much! I new something was wrong there as every pagination example I found talked about that but I was never able to use it without generating massive error about syntax. You mention storing the submitted values in a session? I am unsure of this terminology. Agian I am very much a newbie so I REALLY appreciate it!

Comment: You can store data in the $_SESSION[] array. It is a little bit like the $_GET[] array. The get array will always just contain the data that is in the current URL, while the session array doesnt contain anything on default, but what makes it different from any other array is the fact that it will still be there on the next pages the user goes to. Just Look for some php session tutorials, it is not that hard. Still just putting the _GET parameters in the next link might be the faster/easier fix.

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

`print '<a href="registry.php?page_number='.$suivant.'">next page</a>'; //The link         for the next pages`

**TO**

```
print '<a href="registry.php?page_number='.$next.'">next page</a>'; //The link         for the next pages
```

Comment: $paget doesnt exist either, but you are right, i missed that too. should be $next

Comment: I ran code using my database instead of OPLR it does pagination OK